# Javascript array group by and sum nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, reduce

I need create a scoreboard for these players, based on an array of games. Each game has a final score with multiple p[layers. Each player has a property for what team they played. that property needs to be used to sum up the scores for each game.

The data looks like this:

```
var games = [
  {
      'id': '1',
       "teamOneScore": 10,
       "teamTwoScore": 5,
      'players': [

{
                        "username": "waters",
                        "displayName": "Waters Adkins",
                        "gender": "M",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 2,
                        "appUserId": "86ba61dd-df18-4c42-b788-1d859507bab1"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "whitney",
                        "displayName": "Whitney Winters",
                        "gender": "F",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 1,
                        "appUserId": "c22bfafa-337a-4cbd-840d-e60adeb23625"
                    }
          
      ]
  }, {
      'id': '4',
       "teamOneScore": 25,
       "teamTwoScore": 10,
      'players': [

{
                        "username": "waters",
                        "displayName": "Waters Adkins",
                        "gender": "M",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 2,
                        "appUserId": "86ba61dd-df18-4c42-b788-1d859507bab1"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "whitney",
                        "displayName": "Whitney Winters",
                        "gender": "F",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 1,
                        "appUserId": "c22bfafa-337a-4cbd-840d-e60adeb23625"
                    }
          
      ]
  }, {
      'id': '6',
       "teamOneScore": 10,
       "teamTwoScore": 5,
      'players': [

{
                        "username": "waters",
                        "displayName": "Waters Adkins",
                        "gender": "M",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 2,
                        "appUserId": "86ba61dd-df18-4c42-b788-1d859507bab1"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "whitney",
                        "displayName": "Whitney Winters",
                        "gender": "F",
                        "image": null,
                        "team": 1,
                        "appUserId": "c22bfafa-337a-4cbd-840d-e60adeb23625"
                    }
          
      ]
     
  }
];
```

The result should be an array of players with total score property added to it.

````
 'players': [

{
                        "username": "waters",
                        "displayName": "Waters Adkins",
                        "gender": "M",
                        "totalScore": 20,
                        "appUserId": "86ba61dd-df18-4c42-b788-1d859507bab1",

                    },
                    {
                        "username": "whitney",
                        "displayName": "Whitney Winters",
                        "gender": "F",
                        "totalScore": 45,
                        "appUserId": "c22bfafa-337a-4cbd-840d-e60adeb23625"
                    }
          
      ]```
````

Comment: seems like you should iterate through games array and build up the result

Comment: thanks for the question. Also, add what you tried and what didn't work out. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

1. create an indexing object for `players`. The key is `appUserId` and the value is the `players` `index`.
2. Traverse the `players` of each game to determine if it is an existing or new user.
3. If it's a new user, give them the appropriate score for their team in that game and add them to `palyers`. For existing players, add their score to `totalScore`.

```js
const playersIdx = {}; // variables for indexing
const players = []; // result
games.forEach((game) =>
  game.players.forEach((player) => {
    const findPlayer = playersIdx[player.appUserId] ?? -1;
    const point =  player.team === 1 ? game.teamOneScore : game.teamTwoScore;
    if (findPlayer > -1) {
      players[findPlayer].totalScore += point
    } else {
      const newPlayer = { ...player, totalScore: point }
      delete newPlayer.team
      players.push(newPlayer);
      playersIdx[player.appUserId] = players.length - 1;
    }
  })
);
```